Метод register_next_step_handler: CallbackQuery' object has no attribute 'chat'
Я создаю первого Telegram бота и столкнулся с проблемой, когда пытался через inline button вызвать функцию, получить ответ пользователя и использовать его в другой функции. Пример кода:
def anon_user(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 1)
    register_btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Зарегистрироваться', callback_data = 'register')
    markup.add(register_btn)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чтобы смотреть свою статистику, зарегистрируйтесь', reply_markup = markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_message(call):
    if call.data == 'register':
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Для регистрации введите свой тег:')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call, register)

def register(message):
    global user_id
    user_id = '%23' + message.text[1:]
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы успешно зарегестрировались!')

Появляется ошибка 'CallbackQuery' object has no attribute 'chat' . Как ее исправить?

Объект 'CallbackQuery' не имеет атрибута 'chat'. Как исправить? Открыть документацию..
